# Scala - use cases for tuples?

Tags: scala

In Scala, what are the use cases for tuples? In particular why would I use a tuple instead of creating a case class?

*example*

```
type Average = Double
type Median = Double
type Quantile = Double
type Min = Double
type Max = Double
type StdDev = Double

def stats(times: Seq[Int]): (Average, Median, Quantile, Min, Max, StdDev)
```

vs

```
case class StatResults(average: Double, median: Double, quantile: Double, min: Double, max: Double, stdDev: Double)

def stats(times: Seq[Int]): StatResults
```

Comment: as many people commented, I think the best use case for tuples is when creating Maps. Tuples hurt when you need to evolve your code. I prefer to use case classes which are way more expandable: http://pedrorijo.com/blog/tuples-are-evil/

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the case class is clearly a better idea/design.
However, one frequent use that I make of tuples is typically when I am handling scala [maps](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map), which makes extensive use of them.

Answer (score 0):

Case classes may extend other classes and traits in contrast to `Tuple` agglomeration of classes which extend a `Product` (see for instance [Tuple2](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Tuple2)).

In the use case here, the case class labels each member which may lead to more readable code, in contrast to the 6-tuple reference (`t._1` to `t._6`).

Answer (score 0):

It's convenient to have such data structure for intermediate results. Create classes for results, that returns from your API (or public methods) and use tuples for intermediate results that you discard few lines la

Also, they have some good use cases in collections, for example:

```
Seq(2,3,4).zipWithIndex.foreach { case (element, index) => println(s"$index:$element") }
```